# Sort post by view count in Avada theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Can I sort posts by post's view count in Avada theme?

For example, here:

[image]

Can I write something like this here:

```
postmeta.meta_key = avada_post_views_count
```

or something like that?